# Why does Code::Blocks keep crashing when I try to run this code?

Tags: c

Code::Blocks keeps crashing when I enter the first score in this simple code. It is a perfectly type code to my understanding now I'm confused.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float grade = 0;
    float scoreEntered = 0;
    float numtest = 0;
    float average = 0;

    printf("Press 0 when complete. \n\n");
    do {
        printf("Test: %.0f   Average: %.2f \n", numtest, average);
        printf("\nEnter test score ");
        scanf("%f", scoreEntered);
        grade += scoreEntered;
        numtest++;
        average = grade / numtest;
    } while (scoreEntered != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot ampersand before scanf's second argument.

Comment: `scanf("%f", scoreEntered);` -> `scanf("%f", &scoreEntered);`

Comment: Your program may be crashing, but I doubt it's causing the code blocks ide to crash. Your title seems misleading.

Comment: Thanks buddy... This really got me confused... hahaha. u got me on this one thanks

Comment: Try to compile on the command line with all warnings and debug info, probably with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursourcefile.c -o yourbinprog`. Don't trust too much CodeBlocks (it is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), not a compiler).

Comment: Your fix-my-code question is off-topic on S.O.

Comment: @JosiahSihon: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%f", scoreEntered);
```

should be

```
scanf("%f", &scoreEntered);
```

`scanf` expects address of variable, when you pass variable rather than address of variable, it will end up accessing invalid memory leading to segment fault

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in line 16

it should be

```
scanf("%f", &scoreEntered);
```

**Reason**

"&"  is used to get the address of the variable and "scanf()" needs address of variable to store data

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing `scanf()` the value of `scoreEntered` instead of its address.  You should write:

```
    scanf("%f", &scoreEntered);
```

Note that the compiler can warn you about this kind of silly mistake it you increase the warning level.  Use `gcc -Wall -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Werror` to get maximum help.

Note also that you should test the return value of `scanf()`. If it does not return `1` in the case of a single conversion, the target variable was not modified and the offending input will stay in the input stream, causing the same behavior to repeat indefinitely.  Try typing `A` as input and see for yourself (once you correct the missing `&`).

Here is a corrected and improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float grade = 0;
    float scoreEntered = 0;
    float average = 0;
    int numtest = 0;

    printf("Press 0 when complete.\n");
    for (;;) {
        printf("\nEnter test score: ");
        if (scanf("%f", &scoreEntered) != 1 || scoreEntered == 0)
            break;
        grade += scoreEntered;
        numtest++;
        average = grade / numtest;
        printf("Test: %d   Average: %.2f\n", numtest, average);
    }

    return 0;
}
```